# Jquery error when trying to grab a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get this error in the console when I try to grab a form
the error: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: "#55229c1df3579dd423f9e10b"

```
var formid = '"#' + id + '"';
console.log(formid); this gives this "#55229c1df3579dd423f9e10b" as result
var $replyForm = $(formid);

            $replyForm.submit(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log("reply submitted");
            });
```

Comment: A simple `'#' + id` would work.

Comment: You do not include the `"` when building a selector as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var formid = '#' + id;
```